# Can I make an Infinite Scrolling Background in an SKCamera?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have an SKCamera in my scene and it moves with a ball that can be thrown. I want to make an endless scrolling background, but when I do that, the camera just leaves the background. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the **Vertical** scrolling background like this:

- Creating a background class:

  ```
  import SpriteKit

  class BGClass: SKSpriteNode {

  func moveBG(camera: SKCameraNode) {
      if self.position.y - self.size.height - 10 > camera.position.y {
          self.position.y -= self.size.height * 3
      }
   }
  }
  ```
- Creating 3 background:

  ```
  var bg1 : BGClass?
  var bg2 : BGClass?
  var bg3 : BGClass?
  ```
- Creating a function in GameScene

  ```
  func manageBackgrounds() {
      bg1?.moveBG(mainCamera!)
      bg2?.moveBG(mainCamera!)
      bg3?.moveBG(mainCamera!)
  }
  ```
- Calling manageBackground() in Update:

  ```
  override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
      mangePlayer()
      moveCamera()
      mangeBackgrounds()
      createNewClouds()
  }
  ```

For **Horizontal** scrolling (Add 3 background image after each other and  set camera on the first image):

- change the background class like this:

  ```
  import SpriteKit

  class BGClass: SKSpriteNode {

  func moveBG(camera: SKCameraNode) {
          if self.position.x - self.size.width - 10 > camera.position.x {
      self.position.x -= self.size.width * 3
    }
   }
  }
  ```
- in move camera function:

  ```
  func moveCamera() {
      self.mainCamera?.position.x += 3
  }
  ```

Comment: Is there a way to do Horizontal? @Mina

Comment: my camera is only scrolling horizontally. I'm not 100% sure how to do it.

Comment: is this how I declare the bg's?  @Mina                                                                      var bg1 : BGClass? = BGClass(imageNamed: "Trees")
    var bg2 : BGClass? = BGClass(imageNamed: "Trees")
    var bg3 : BGClass? = BGClass(imageNamed: "Trees")

Comment: I've added the background nodes in .sks file, so i called them like this: `bg1 = self.childNodeWithName("BG1") as? BGClass`

Comment: Just add 3 sprite nodes, gives them names in GameScene.sks file, and use them in GameScene.swift file like the way i said.
`self.childNodeWithName("BG1")` find a node which named "BG1" in .sks file, as? `as? BGClass  ` cast it to our custom class named `BGClass `.

Comment: Hey @Mina, I need some help. I still haven't figured it out and I need help.

Comment: @JoshSchlabach, how can i help you?

Comment: could we TeamView? It's really complicated.

Comment: whats your email

Comment: I sent you an email!

Comment: Mina did you get it? @Mina